# Google Maps API Marker, Wordpress and jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I managed to implement Google Maps Api, and load the markers from the Wordpress database via the functions. But I can not figure out how to add custom icon to the marker pin. The problem is that Wordpress does not allow direct access to template files.

My image is loaded in themes/themename/img/bgi

The script looks like this:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude,data[i].longitude);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            //icon: data[i].image,
                            map: map,
                            title: data[i].title
                    });
```

Comment: Have you not read the Google Maps API documentation?

Comment: i have read it, multiple times. there is no specification for wordpress or php loading of markers icon. or maybe i haven't found it...

Comment: Why would the Google Maps API v3 documentation say anything about wordpress or PHP?  It does tell you how to implement a [custom marker icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#SimpleIcons).

Comment: The icon property takes either a string or MarkerObject. Why would you have to load anything through Wordpress or PHP? From your code snippet it looks like your iterating through an array to generate multiple coordinates and icons...

Comment: Is the same custom icon used for all the markers?  What is its filename? (or is it bgi?)

Comment: Thanks for the help! The documentation provided by google tells indeed how to implement the marker icon. The problem is, i know the path to the image file (wp-content/themes/themename/img/bgi/marker.png) but the script can not access the image. i think it is because of wordpress htaccess and directory access restriction.

Comment: @TudorRavoiu The icon image needs to be somewhere accessible via public HTTP

Comment: Thanky you @GadyP. Do you know how can i public allow acces to the img/bgi/marker.png (folder and file), inside my wp-theme folder?

Comment: @TudorRavoiu Put them in www instead

Answer (score 2):

I used the following for my solution - absolute paths to the file in the theme directory:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/marker.png
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/marker-shadow.png
```

so you have:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/marker.png',
    new google.maps.Size(60,78),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(30,78)
);
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/marker-shadow.png',
    new google.maps.Size(105,78),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(30,78)
);
```